# OLEDB provider/connection issue on Azure server

Tags: azure, oledb

The Azure server is not supporting the OLEDB provider/connection. We need the Export and Import functionality of MS-Excel file.
So the import function is throwing the below error.

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: What Azure service are you using?

Comment: We are using App services .. shared hosting. Let us know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

That driver can be installed from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

I believe it is 32-bit only so if you need 64-bit then look for the [Office 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) or above version that comes in 64-bit.

Now how you go about installing that in App Service I don't know. Maybe someone else will.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install drivers using App Services.  You need to look at Virtual Machines or Cloud Services (Web Role).